# Article after a comma

Tags: meaning, article, relative-pronoun

I'm reading a story, and it says:

> Der Bär sah die rostigen, schmalen Schienen, **die zum Bergwerk
> führten**, und sagte: „Ich würde gerne mal in die Mine reinspazieren
> und mir ein funkeliges Goldstückchen holen.“

And I don't understand the grammar and meaning of the bolded sentence. For example, what is the article *die* role here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an article, but a relative pronoun. The relevant parts of the sentence translate to:

> The bear saw the rusty, narrow rails, which were leading to the mine, and said:

*die* in the German sentence corresponds to *which* in the English sentence.